# Ionic Maps - Fitting map inside a small part of the view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I've created a very simple Ionic Maps App (using [this template](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps)), and it works fine, both in the browser and on my devices. As you know, the default maps template produces an app which looks something like this:

[image]

I've got the default template code.But now i'm trying to change it to **make the map fit a small part of the view** (on the top-right corner).

I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

I thought this could be done with simple CSS (fiddling around with the width and height of the map element), so I went to the style.css and tried changing it.

However, **if I change it to something other than 100%**, and if I change "display" to something other than "block", **the map simply disappears** all together.

What I tried:

- **Changing the width/height/display of the map element**. If I do it, the map simply disappears, or appears in front of the other elements (text & buttons of the main view);
- **Fitting it inside the ionic grid's "col" div**. Does not work;
- **Fitting the other content inside the Ionic grid**. It does not work - the map is always shown in front of the other elements.

**EDIT: What worked:**

- I had to *remove the  wrapper for the  directive.* I believe this, among other things, prevented the item inside to be treated in the way I described here.

Many thanks for Prashant for his time and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried playing around with the ionic starter maps project and here's what worked for me:

**Update: (Exactly what you want)**

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content scroll="false">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col col-50 col-center">
        <h3>Some heading</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-50">
        <div style="height: 150px; width: 100%;">
          <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="padding">
      <a href="#" class="button button-block button-calm">Some button</a>
      <a href="#" class="button button-block button-positive">Another button</a>
    </div>

  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
    <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate"></a>
  </ion-footer-bar>

</body>
```

**Result:**

[image: Small Map for ionic]

Comment: I tried avoiding float because I thought it would conflict with the grid but I guess I have no choice. I will test it soon, and if works on all my devices - I will follow your way. Thank you!

Comment: Float was just to prove it works. I will put a better version in the next edit. no worries.

Comment: Ok, I understand what the problem was on my behalf. I didn't remove the <ion-content> wrapper element, which I suspect was preventing the map to be treated the way I want. Thanks again Prashant!

Comment: No problem. Cheers! :)